# C# templating access to object members

Tags: c#, generic-programming

I want to be able to create a function that does a generic action on any member variable.

```
class line
{
    double angle;
    double length;
    public void add(reference member, double scalar)
    {
        this.member *= scalar;
    }
}
```

Is this possible in C#. If I have many member variables, I don't want to create a giant switch case. I also don't want to create one lambda function for each member variable seeing as the operation would be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of @askpark's answer I've come up with something simpler

```
class line
{
    double angle;
    double length;

    public void delegate adder(line l, double d);
    static adder angleAdder = (l,d) => {l.angle += d};
    static adder lengthAdder = (l,d) => {l.length += d};

    public void add(adder addFunc, double scalar)
    {
        addFunc(this, scalar);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use Action<line, double> instead of creation a new delegate

Answer (score 0):

No need for generics. You'll have to overload for different scalar types, though. There's no way to do arithmetic on scalars with generics in C#. For that you'd need a type constraint `where T : scalar` which, unfortunately, doesn't exist (and possibly can't).

```
class line
{
    double angle;
    double length;

    public void add(ref double member, double scalar)
    {
        member *= scalar;
    }

    public void test()
    {
        add(ref angle, 12);
    }

}
```

You could also define this as an extension method for any class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static double add(this object o, ref double d1, double d2)
        => d1 *= d2;
}
```

But then you have to explicitly prefix it with `this.`:

```
private double _x = 1.0;
public void Test()
{
    //  "The name 'add' does not exist in the current context"
    add(ref _x, 1.2);

    //  This compiles
    this.add(ref _x, 1.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use reflection as follows, now can operate like this: `line.Add(l => l.Length, 10)` or `line.Add("Length", 10)` or `line.Add(nameof(line.Length), 10)`(env >.net 4.5)

you can also iterate special members like this:`(new List<string> { "Length", "Height" }).ForEach(p => line.Add(p, 10))`

```
class Line
{
    public int Length { get; set; }

    public double Height { get; set; }

    public void Add<O>(Expression<Func<Line, O>> accessor, dynamic scale) where O : struct
    {
        Add((accessor.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name, scale);//simply get name from expression
    }

    public void Add(string name, dynamic scale)
    {
        var prop = typeof(Line).GetProperty(name);//can also get all members
        dynamic a = prop.GetValue(this);
        prop.SetValue(this, a * scale);
    }
}
```